# Either Photo or Live Face How to check with Android Camera

Tags: android, ios, camera, face-recognition

I am using Luxand  Library for Face Recognition in my android app.
App have 2 step for face recognition.
1. In step1 It open device camera and capture user's  pic and save it on phone.
2.Recognition step: In this step Library does Face recognition .it open camera and compare with saved pic.and  its working fine.

But my issue is In FaceRecognition step when i show a user's photo in front of camera instead showing Live Face it recognized user.So how to check it is face or a photo.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem too on my project.I know that developer use thermal camera for this problem. But I heard a library for this problem ,now I cant remember name of it, if I can I will add here.It should be C++ library. However probably this library wont work on android, So this is so complex issue and as you know there are too few argument on internet.